# Codeigniter Htaccess and URL Redirect issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use `.htaccess` on CodeIgniter, but it is not working.

I have already set:

```
AllowOverride All
```

```php
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I am using XAMPP on Windows.

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My URL still contains `index.php` and, if I try to remove it manually, it returns a 404 error

Also my other concern is my login page: whenever I login, my URL is stuck on the check page.

I was wondering how do I rewrite my URL to change to home page instead of staying on the check page.

```
public function check(){
        $this->load->model('check');
        $logcheck = $this->check->check($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'));

        if($logcheck == "admin"){
            $this->load->view('home');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got the htaccess to work by transferring it from application folder to my root folder. wonder why they place it there if you need to move it anyway

Comment: Every folder has it's own htaccess file that prevents crowling particular (system) folders such are application or system. You sould leave it there with content as is. For root folder you need to create very own .htaccess file.

Comment: What URL currently you getting after login and what URL you expected

Comment: @ShaifulIslam after login it is: Phonebook/check/, what i want is it to be Phonebook/home/. how do can i change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple .htaccess will remove your index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Change your check function like this

```
 public function check(){
    $this->load->model('check');
    $logcheck = $this->check->check($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'));

    if($logcheck == "admin"){
        //may  be you need to set login credential into session
        redirect('Phonebook/home/');
        //$this->load->view('home');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

and your home function will be like this

```
public function home(){
      //remember you need to check login validation from session
      $this->load->view('home');
}
```

to use `redirect` function remember you have `url` helper loaded.
May be this help you

Comment: Thank you it woks great, question though can i remove the controller from the URL using htaccess?

Comment: can you direct me to an example? thank you and much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you go to this place here http://www.insiderclub.org/downloads and then click on the link "HERE IT IS" download the htaccess zip folder there are about 5 different suited ones for codeigniter for htaccess

Not sure where this **AllowOverride All** comes into play?

Also

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Make

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

**Make sure you have configured your route.php**

Main htaccess root. You do not need to touch the other .htaccess

The first one you will find in zip is this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Seems to work fine with my xampp and codeigniter 2 & 3 but try the ones on download.

This is the second one in zip folder for htaccess think more for wamp etc.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```