# Removing index.php from URL in CodeIgniter on Mandriva

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, httpd.conf

I developed a project which uses CodeIgniter on Windows OS. The project works fine on XAMPP (Windows) and Linux hosting server (updated .htaccess on server to work). I want to use Open Mandriva for development purpose. If I run the controller using index.php, it works.

I tried many .htaccess rules examples, links. But controller is not loading.

I tried: [Cannot remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url), [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) and 
[this external link](http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2013/12/steps-to-remove-indexphp-from.html), and many other links.

.htaccess code on Windows machine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

.htaccess code on Linux hosting server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Both are not working on Open Mandriva.

.htaccess path

```
/srv/www/html/ci/
```

The page gives:

> 404 error, and Object not found!

The file system path to my project is

```
/srv/www/html/ci/application/controllers/
```

and on browser:

```
localhost/ci/branch
```

Project works if I add index.php like

```
localhost/ci/index.php/branch
```

Is it having any relation with http server config? Do I need to install any package. Also I tried some commands for apache rewrite engine. But I get error as unknown command.

Comment: Please could you share the current content of your `.htaccess` file? This will help us to help you.

Comment: Where are your files stored? At the document root? And why do you need to check `/system.*`?

Comment: .htaccess is stored at same level of application or system folder. Actually I am not having any knowledge about htaccess rules. The code worked so I kept it for respective platforms.

Comment: Off-topic: I recently commented on one of your answers, which you can copy-and-pasted from [another of your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30026152/472495). I think deleting the copy was the correct course of action, but why did you delete the original? That was fine: if that itself was not a copy, I suggest you reinstate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if rewrite engine is [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9021425/3843374).

If not, enable rewrite engine and restart server.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Go to

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf - for Mandriva
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf  - for Ubuntu
```

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Code block:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

Restart Apache(httpd) service.

No changes required in `config.php` or anywhere else.

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then, in `config.php`:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Please ensure that your `.htaccess` is located in the same directory as your `index.php`.

Comment: Please could you share what errors you are getting? What happens when you try to access `example.com/your-controller`?

Comment: The page gives 404 error, and Object not found! The file system path to my project is /srv/www/html/ci/application/controllers/ and on browser, http://localhost/ci/branch/  Project works if I add index.php like http://localhost/ci/index.php/branch/

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517126/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-redirect-issues/28517329#28517329

Comment: The path to your project should be `/srv/www/html/ci/` as that is the CodeIgniter root. That is where your `.htaccess` file should be stored.

Comment: Yes. The file is there.

Comment: Please see my amended answer - I have added `RewriteBase /ci/`

Comment: Then I'm afraid I've tried everything I can think of right now... Good luck!

Comment: Is it having any relation with http server config? Do I need to install any package. Also I tried some commands for apache rewrite engine. But I get error as unknown command.

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing I can think of is that your `mod_rewrite` may not be enabled...

Comment: Ah, right! (Always seems to be the last thing I check for.) Well done :)